# got a random file names imgres.html

Tags: javascript, html, malware-detection

So I was opening visual studio code and I saw that I have a new html file that I don't remember having previously. It is  247,365 characters and 4,354 words.
does anyone know what this is?(it also includes js)
I cant send the code since the limit is 3k characters

Comment: Impossible to tell without access to your computer's files.

Comment: @Spectric is there any way I can send it to you?

Comment: I believe this is the result of a Google Images search. You accidentally downloaded it to your computer.